# How to set request timeout in vertx webclient

Tags: java, vert.x

I am trying to setup requestTimeout in vert.x web-client. But its not working as expected.

An api with < 10ms response time is timing out from webclient with 100ms requestTimeout set. Both the server and client are running on my local machine.

```
@Test
  public void connectionTimeOut() throws InterruptedException {
    WebClient  client = WebClient.create(Vertx.vertx());
    client.request(HttpMethod.GET,8000 , "localhost", "/scripts/").timeout(100).send(ar -> {
      if (ar.succeeded()) {
        System.out.print("Request  succeded");

      } else {
        ar.cause().printStackTrace(); ;
      }
    });

    TimeUnit.MINUTES.sleep(20);
  }
```

```
java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: The timeout period of 100ms has been exceeded while executing GET /scripts/ for host localhost
    at io.vertx.core.http.impl.HttpClientRequestBase.timeout(HttpClientRequestBase.java:183)
    at io.vertx.core.http.impl.HttpClientRequestBase.handleTimeout(HttpClientRequestBase.java:168)
    at io.vertx.core.http.impl.HttpClientRequestBase.lambda$setTimeout$0(HttpClientRequestBase.java:126)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.VertxImpl$InternalTimerHandler.handle(VertxImpl.java:870)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.VertxImpl$InternalTimerHandler.handle(VertxImpl.java:829)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.ContextImpl.lambda$wrapTask$2(ContextImpl.java:344)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute$$$capture(AbstractEventExecutor.java:163)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute(AbstractEventExecutor.java)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:404)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:463)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:886)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

The same code works if I set requestTimeout to 1000ms. Please let me know if there is any workaround for this or if I am missing something.

Comment: Are you running in debug mode?

Comment: No. I have executed this as a junit test case.

Comment: I would suggest using the vert.x unit testing framework and using their methods for testing your code [here](https://vertx.io/docs/vertx-unit/java/#_junit_integration) for more details on working with it and JUnit. 

You can then test the asynchronous code in a more natural way by using it. 
You may want to use the [Async](https://vertx.io/docs/vertx-unit/java/#_asynchronous_assertions) object as well when testing this way.

Comment: Yes. Agree its a better way to test vertex code. But I dont think it would effect requestTimeout in webclient.

Comment: Can you make sure with Wireshark that the backend actually replies?